# Hibernate Search 5.11 indexNullAs does not work

Tags: hibernate, elasticsearch, lucene, hibernate-search

I have a nullable column in my indexed entity and I want to filter out entities that have `null` in corresponding field. I am using Elasticsearch as an indexmanager.

```
@Field(analyze = Analyze.NO, indexNullAs = "2999-12-31")
@Column(name = "nullable_date")
private LocalDate nullableDate;
```

I have used `indexNullAs` attribute in the `Field` annotation and, if I understand documentation correctly, `null` values should be replaced with `"2999-12-31"` value in the index.
But in Elasticsearch this field has an actual `null` value instead of `"2999-12-31"` string that I specified in annotation:

```
"nullableDate": null,
```

This field is in the root indexed entity (not IndexedEmbedded entity so it is not this issue https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2389).

I have tried a query like `+nullableDate:null` and sent it to `createFullTextQuery` method, but I get `failed to parse date field [null] with format [strict_date||yyyyyyyyy-MM-dd]` error from Elasticsearch. Also I have tried queries like `+nullableDate:2999-12-31` and apparently I get the empty result (since field has `null` value in Elastic).

Does it mean that `indexNullAs` does not work properly (is it https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3099 issue?) or I am using it in a wrong way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your query, not with indexing. `indexNullAs` does work for `LocalDate` on `Elasticsearch` (I just double-checked that).

How do you build your queries? If you're using `indexNullAs`, you should probably use our DSL.

In any case, this works:

```
        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = session.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity( MyEntity.class ).get();
        Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword()
                .onField( "nullableDate" )
                .matching( LocalDate.of( 2999, Month.DECEMBER, 31 ) )
                .createQuery();
        result = session.createFullTextQuery( luceneQuery, MyEntity.class ).list();
```

And this too:

```
        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = session.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity( MyEntity.class ).get();
        Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword()
                .onField( "nullableDate" )
                .matching( null )
                .createQuery();
        result = session.createFullTextQuery( luceneQuery, MyEntity.class ).list();
```

The fact that Hibernate Search is sending "null" is expected, and is actually a feature: it allows to properly retrieve null when using projections. As to indexing, the Elasticsearch mapping (i.e. the schema) generated by Hibernate Search and pushed to Elasticsearch should include something like this:

```
properties: {
    ...

    "nullableDate": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyyyyyyy-MM-dd",
        "null_value": "2999-12-31"

    }

    ...

}
```

The `null_value` part means that whenever Elasticsearch receives a null value, it will index it as "2999-12-31". Which is exactly what you wanted.

On a side note, [HSEARCH-3099](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3099) is only a task to remind us to add this feature in Hibernate Search 6; it does not affect 5.11 at all.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Actually, I am implementing an API that consumes lucene query. I use `QueryParser` to parse the query string to `org.apache.lucene.search.Query` object that is sent to `FullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery` method. I will try to hardcode the example you sent to check if it is working and after that will try to map it to a corresponding query string.

Comment: I tried proposed approach with DSL, but it gave me empty result. After that I checked the schema in Elasticsearch for that field and I got this: `"nullableDate": {
"type": "date",
"format": "strict_date||yyyyyyyyy-MM-dd"
},` so there is no `"null_value":` attribute. Do I need to add any additional configuration to enable it? I have Elasticsearch version 5.6.x

Comment: I had to change `index_schema_management_strategy` to `drop-and-create` so the schema was updated. Is there any way of executing schema update without changing `index_schema_management_strategy` property (for example doing it on demand when the data structure is changed or some fields become nullable, etc.)?

Comment: Unfortunately no, that's not possible yet. We do know it would be useful in some cases, but it's simply not made its way to the top of our to-do list yet. But you can open a ticket detailing the feature and how you would imagine the APIs: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HSEARCH

Comment: Update: manually triggered schema updates will be available in Hibernate Search 6.0.0.Beta6, since we solved this ticket: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3759